# In C++ is it possible to call an accessor through property-like syntax?

Tags: c++, refactoring, encapsulation, accessor

I am working with a large code base, and there are a number of publicly defined variables.  Unfortunately, the functions of accessing these variables has changed, and this new functionality would be best encapsulated by public accessors and a private instance variable.

So, I am trying to make this change.  To do so, I planned to make each public property private and then create accessors.  But, I don't want to change any of the code which accesses the old public properties.  For example:

After changing the public property to private, I have the following class:

```
class Test {

    private:
        int item = 5;

    public:
        int GetItem() {
             return item;
        };

        void SetItem(int new_item) {
             item = new_item;
        };
};
```

In the past, "item" used to be a public property of the class, and it was accessed through:

```
Test* t = new Test();
int item = t->item;
```

Now though, I need to add new functionality to the way in which "item" is retrieved.  For example:

```
int GetItem() {
     //  Some complicated code which changes "item"
     return item;
};
```

How can I keep the same syntax:

```
int item = t->item;
```

But have this actually perform:

```
int item = t->GetItem();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, C++ is a compiled non-reflective language, i.e. you can't just "look names up as you access an element", because in the binary, there are no names anymore. Also, please don't let your C++ become Java just for the sake of having getters and setters – if they don't actually add security, I don't really see the point of using them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If they existed, properties wouldn't need any reflection or run-time support. They could purely be syntactic sugar for method calls that is expanded by the compiler. Of course, they don't exist, but not for the reasons you imply.

Comment: encapsulation via getters and setter is done for a reason, if this reason is absent you dont need getters and setters just for the sake of encapsulation

Comment: _"it was accessed through: `Test t = new Test();`"_ I doubt it. That won't even compile.

Comment: @delnan if they existed, such syntax-sugary properties would lead to paradoxes – what's the address of that property? What's its type? No, with a strictly statically typed language, having such properties can lead to great inconveniences.

Comment: @lightness This `Test t = new Test()` is the instance creation and not the item access and I think it would work - Just to take your attention

Comment: @FirstStep well, `new` gives you a pointer, so access to elements of the generated object would need dereferencing first, which OP doesn't do. It should be giving you something like "Can't access element `item` of pointer type `t`".

Comment: @FirstStep: Well, you're wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: `t` is not a `Test*` here. It is a `Test`. The example code is nonsense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am not saying it would be a good idea, but there is no paradox, only behavior that needs to be specified and that may have multiple possible behaviors that are intuitive to different people (e.g. one possibility is *always* treating `x.prop` as `x.GetProp()` so the type would just be the return type and the address would be the address of a temporary). Also consider that C# has such properties, so there is nothing inherently incompatible with static typing about them.

Comment: This is totally possible but there are many different ways to achieve it.  Unless you can find a stable library version of a *property* class it may be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: @lightness I've updated the example.  Sorry about that, I should have compiled before posting.  I think my head was stuck in Java land.

Comment: @tobi303 I believe in this situation the accessors were not needed at first, but now they are needed.  To me, it seems it would be a good idea to add accessors if that encapsulation may be needed in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `int item = t.item;` work, by defining `item` as a member variable whose type is a helper class with a custom conversion `operator int()` defined.  Also, `operator=(int new_value)` to intercept the set operation.

What you can't make work is

```
int& item = t.item;
```

or

```
int* pitem = &t.item;
```

because both of these enable direct memory access, without going through any getter or setter.  When creating the reference or pointer, you can't even determine how many accesses there will be or whether they will be reads or writes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  In my case however, I needed to do this with pointers, so I ended up manually changing much of the codebase.

Answer (score 1):

In case that your question is based in the fact that you don't want to call 2 different functions for setting and getting, you can make a function that returns a reference of the member:

```
int& Item()
{
     // Some complicated code which changes *items
     return item;
}
```

as you can see, the return type is int& instead of int. so you can use this function this way

```
t.Item() = someValue;
```

Comment: Thank you for this information.  In my case though, I wish to leave the existing codebase untouched while adding this new functionality.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a compiled non-reflective language, i.e. you can't just "look names up as you access an element", because in the binary, there are no names anymore.

So, no, what you want is impossible. (at least not without restrictions – see Ben Voigt's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36799061/4433386); having a "transparent" property which is in fact a getter call surely isn't worth the pitfalls you're building with that-)

Also, please don't let your C++ become Java just for the sake of having getters and setters – if they don't actually add security, I don't really see the point of using them

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Ben Voight's answer, you can define a proxy template that allows this without the boiler plate:

```
template <typename Return, typename Containing, Return (Containing::* func)()>
struct proxy
{
   Containing& c;
   proxy(Containing& c) : c(c) {}
   operator Return() { return (c.*func)(); }
   Return& operator=(const Return& r) { return (c.*set)() = r; }
 };
```

Then to define a "property"

```
class c {
   int y_;
   int get_y() { std::cout << "Getting y" << std::endl; return y_; }
public:
   proxy<int, x, &x::get_y> y;
   c() : y(*this) {}
};
```

And in client code

```
int main() {
   c val;
   val.y = 5;
   std::cout << val.y << std::endl;
}
```